# When I update a datetime record in MySQL using PHP the datetime is 1 hour ahead of my time, how do I change this?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, timezone

I have my users stored in a MySQL table and when the user logs in, I update a column called acc_lastlogin to the current datetime, so I can keep track of when users login. However, it's always 1 hour ahead when I look at the record.

So if it's 13:30 and a user logs in, in the database it'll show that the user last logged in at 14:30. I have a php.ini file which has

```
date.timezone = "Europe/London"
```

The php.ini file is in my main directory but the script is inside a folder in the same directory, not sure if that makes any difference.

How can I set it so the time is correct?

Also, to get the current datetime i'm using this

```
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Is MySQL set to use UTC/GMT? Europe/London is currently GMT+1.

Comment: Do you really need in timezone component? if not then simply change the datatype from TIMESTAMP to DATETIME.

Comment: I'm not sure, i'm using 1and1 for hosting and phpmyadmin. How would I check?

Comment: My apologies, it is a datetime column

Comment: Try `show globals like '%zone%'` in MySQL, it will show you what the timezone is set for.

Comment: How are you writing to the DB, with `$timestamp`, `now()`, default value?

Comment: @user3783243 i've updated my question to show how i'm getting the current datetime

Comment: How are you writing it to the DB?